# Best way to save and edit text data without a database

Tags: php, html

This is a rather odd question but here it goes:

I have this web app that i'm developing where i've set some of the page titles, descriptions into array.

```
         $config = [
              'page-1' : [
                    'title': 'Page 1 Title',
                    'desc': 'Lorem ipsum.....',
              ],
              'page-2' : [
                    'title': 'Page 2 Title',
                    'desc': 'Lorem ipsum.....',
              ]
         ];

         <div class="title"><?=$config[$_GET['pageid']]['title']?></div>
         <div class="description"><?=$config[$_GET['pageid']]['description']?></div>
```

Now i was wondering is it possible to edit and save that data in dashboard without using databases??

I saw some posts saying that editing server side variables is impossible but maybe there's other ways i could store and edit that data directly??

Honestly i'm just wondering, i could store everything in a database but maybe i shouldnt?

EDIT: JSON is something i've thought about but then it's publicly viewable and it's not exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: JSON doesn't make your file viewable, it is just a way of turning arrays and objects into a string that can be converted back again. Where you store your files (and what permissions you give to the containing folder, plus use of .htaccess etc.) is what determines whether people can see the contents or not.

Comment: You can use a client side database such as localstorage or indexeddb. All data is stored on the clients browser

Answer (score 0):

You could just save information as files on your server. Php allows you to do so using file_put_contents. Something like this:

```
<?php
$file = 'config.txt';

// to open the file use this:
$currentFile = file_get_contents($file);

//you can simply append like so
$current .= "'page-3: ['title': 'my title']";

//then write into $current into a file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Read more here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Now given your example, you probably want to convert the file into usable data. You could simply use include() to bring in the data, then modify it, and use file_put_contents() to rewrite the included file.

Comment: A flat file is also a type of database.

Comment: That's a very open interpretation of a database. I took 'database' to mean, you know, an actual database. I suppose if 'database' means anything saved server-side, then I don't know what the OP wants. Certainly anything stored client-side is both temporary and potentially a security risk.